# How to extract last several commits to the branch and reset to some previous commit?

Tags: git

I screwed up with several commits in a row.

What I want to do is:

1. Extract last several commits to the specific branch
2. Revert master to the normal commit
3. Carefully fix changes in that branch (p1) and continuously add them back to the master.

Would it fix the problem and if so, how to implement this plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repo looks like this.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
```

Let's say C and D are the commits you don't want on master.

First, make a new branch on the same commit as master.

```
$ git branch feature

A - B - C - D [master]
              [feature]
```

Then move master back to B with `git reset`.

```
$ git reset --hard B

A - B [master]
     \ 
      C - D [feature]
```

Now you can check out and work on feature.

---

What if you didn't reset and reverted instead? Unlike reset, which moves the branch label, revert makes new commits.

We start as before.

```
A - B - C - D [master]
```

And as before we make a new branch to remember the commits we want to work on.

```
$ git branch feature

A - B - C - D [master]
              [feature]
```

Instead of moving master so it no longer contains the offending commits, we use revert to add a new commit to master which undoes C and D.

```
$ git revert C D

A - B - C - D [feature]
             \
              ^D - ^C [master]
```

The content of master will be the same as commit B, but the history will be messier. You generally don't want to preserve artifacts of the development process like reverts and simple typo fixes, they're of no use to future developers and make the history more difficult to understand.

Because of this, I recommend leaving revert for deeply buried commits.

Comment: Will my history be saved somehow somewhere? What if do several reverts instead of hard reset?

Comment: @mimic If by "history" you mean "commits", yes. The drawings above are accurate. A branch in Git is just a label on a commit. You'd only be moving labels around. The commits are unchanged.

Comment: @mimic I've also demonstrated the revert procedure.

Comment: I have a problem. When I reset to a specific commit and then try to add changes and push I had an error I have to pull first. When I pull all the changes done AFTER (those I want to reset) came back. What do I have to do??

Comment: @mimic You needed to have mentioned you'd already pushed your changes, that changes the situation. All that would have been required is a `git push --force-with-lease`, but now that you've pulled I don't know the state of your repository. Stop issuing any remote commands (push and pull). Post `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`, commit messages scrubbed,  somewhere, like [Gist](https://gist.github.com/). And we'll get it fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217481/discussion-between-schwern-and-mimic).

Comment: After I pulled I canceled pulling :) so now I'm fine pushing with --force